# Lumen Get request and query not working

Tags: laravel, lumen

This is the function I am calling in my controller

```
    public function searchColors(Request $request)
    {
       $die = $request['die'];
       $colors = DB::table('paintline')->where('die', '=', $die)
                            ->get();

        return response()->json(['colors' => $colors], 200);
    }
```

The route

```
$app->group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function($app) {

    $app->get('/info/{die}', [
        'uses' => 'PaintLineController@searchColors'
    ]);
});
```

If I hardcode the die value in my controller like this it returns 2 rows

```
 $colors = DB::table('paintline')->where('die', '=', '9ISF4')
                            ->get();
```

But if I use postman or firefox to test this url it returns just this `{"colors":[]}`

`myApp.app/api/v1/info/9ISF4`

Comment: Laravel/Lumen passes path parameters as an argument to the controller. So you can get the value of `/info/{die}` like `public function searchColors($die, Request $request)`

Comment: It worked! Thanks @jfadich

Answer (score 0):

If you use this expression in your route file:

```
$app->get('/info/{die}', [
    'uses' => 'PaintLineController@searchColors'
]);
```

Then `die` will be passed as argument in your controller method (the Route is responsible in this case), thus it's not accessible via `\Illuminate\Http\Request`. To access your `die` "variable", change your controller method into something like this:

```
public function searchColors(string $die, Request $request)
{
    // dd($die);
}
```